# swiftui what is the safe way to put a view on the top of screen?

Tags: swiftui, responsive

please check this picture first:[image]

as you see, there are some distance from status bar.
if I want to put the highlight texts to this place,I have to add a fixaul padding to a view,
but if user is using a small screen device, will it out of screen?
is there any safe way to put a text away from status bar?

thanks for your help. have a nice day :)

Comment: It shouldn't get cut off... you can test in the previews or by using different simulators

Comment: @aheze that ease my mind, thank you !